# Angular URLSearchParams not working for multiple params

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have an Asp.Net web api controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult RepHistorie([FromUri]string vnr, [FromUri]string lagerort)
{
    ...
}
```

So you can see that there are 2 values.
I am using URLSearchParams for sending the parameters. Unfortunately this doesn't work for more than one param. I don't know why and this is really strange to me.

```
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('vnr', this.vnr);
params.set('lagerort', this.lagerort);

var postUrl = 'http://123.456.7.89:12345/api/lager';

let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.search = params;

this.http.post(postUrl, requestOptions)
  .subscribe(data => {
    // success

  }, error => {
    // error
});
```

In my other controller there is only one parameter and it works perfectly. Does someone know why?

I also tried:

```
params.append('vnr', this.vnr);
params.append('lagerort', this.lagerort);
```

**Edit**

It works like this (Isn't a clean way though):

```
var postUrl = 'http://123.456.7.89:12345/api/lager?vnr=' + this.vnr + '&lagerort=' + this.lagerort;
var postObject = {};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue before noticing that i had not imported it, 
**you have to import URLSearchParams before using it**.

```
import {URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
```

Enjoy coding!

Comment: I don't know how much time I wasted with that!

Comment: This did it for me also, it's weird that my editor didn't throw a fit like it usually does whenever I try using something without importing it.

Comment: @Jon Probably because there's a native one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the following

```
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('vnr', this.vnr);
    params.set('lagerort', this.lagerort);
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.params = params; // instead of requestOptions.search = params
```